# django ForeignKey model filter in admin-area?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I need really very very simple example. First my models:

```
#This my student models
from django.db import models
SEX_CHOICES= (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
class Students(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    student_city = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    student_bio = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

O.K. Let see my Classes Model.

```
#This my Classes models
from django.db import models
from myproject.students.models import *
class Classes(models.Model):
    class_number= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class_student_cities = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    class_year = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.class_number
```

My classes/admin.py file looks like that:

```
from myproject.classes.models import *
from myproject.students.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class ClassesChoiceField(Students):
    class_student_cities = Classes.objects.get(id=1).class_student_cities.student_city

admin.site.register(Classes)
```

I get this error:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/classes/classes/add/
Classes matching query does not exist.
```

How can i show in the **class_student_cities** area the **Students.student_city** datas? **I guess that about django-admin area.**
When i do it with **ForeignKey(Students)** i just see in that area the **Students.student_name** data :S. I'm really wondering how can I do it? Can you give me a little example?
Many Thanks!

Comment: Where are u trying to display Students.student_city, in admin?

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Comment: What don't you understand? Be specific.

Comment: But not in any useful way, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

To get student_city from queryset, you can use:

```
Classes.objects.get(id=1).class_student_cities.student_city
```

And if you want to relate your foreignkey field not to primary key, you should use `to_field` argument

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

It will be like:

```
class_student_cities = models.ForeignKey(Students, to_field='student_city')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems -- basically things are 'not quite right', which is why you keep being referred to the docs.

Here is an example of what an admin.py should look like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from articles.models import Article

def show_articletype_thumbnail(self):
    return self.image.admin_thumbnail()
show_articletype_thumbnail.allow_tags=True
show_articletype_thumbnail.short_description = 'Image'


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
    list_display = ['status', 'articletype', 'issue', 'penname', 'issue', show_articletype_thumbnail]
    list_display_links = ['articletype']
    list_filter = ['articletype', 'allow_comments', 'template', 'issue']

admin.site.register(Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Comment: Still not working, same error...



`from myproject.classes.models import *
from myproject.students.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class ClassesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class_student_cities = Classes.objects.get(id=1).class_student_cities.student_city

admin.site.register(Classes,ClassesAdmin)`